# Connect R to Filemaker Pro 15 on Mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, filemaker, rodbc

I'm trying to create a connection between R (3.3.3) Using RStudio (1.0.143) and Filemaker Pro Advanced 15 (15.0.3.305). I'm trying to create the connection using RODBC (1.3-15).

So far I:

[Created a toy FM Pro database for testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzszyehxvpvilzp/test_r.fmp12?dl=0)

- User id: Admin
- Password: password

[Followed these instructions for creating a DSN](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/15/en/fm15_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf)

Created a DSN for my toy FM Pro database called test_r

[image]

Successfully tested the connection to test_r

[image]

Unsuccessfully attempted to connect to the DSN in RStudio in the following two ways:

```
fm_connection <- odbcConnect(dsn="test_r", uid="Admin", pwd="password")
```

Which returns the following error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specifiedODBC connection failed
```

AND

```
constr <- paste("driver={FileMaker ODBC}",
               "server=127.0.0.1",
               "database=test_r",
               "uid=Admin",
               "pwd=password",
               sep=";")

fm_connection <- odbcDriverConnect(constr)
```

Which returns the following error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FileMaker ODBC' : file not foundODBC connection failed
```

However, you can see that the driver is there:[image]

Finally, I've unsuccessfully tried using these (and other) references to resolve this issue:

1. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf
2. https://community.filemaker.com/thread/165849

Nothing seems to work so far. I'm not tied to RODBC, but I do need a solution that works for **Mac OS**. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to create a User DSN instead of System DSN. FileMaker ODBC is a connection to a FileMaker Database, make sure test_r is open.

Comment: @NicolaiKant thanks for the suggestions. Created the User DSN. The Filemaker data was open. Same error.

Comment: Are you using 32 bit R install by any chance, as this might cause a problem.

Comment: @NicolaiKant 64-bit

Comment: IS ODBC sharing on in FileMaker and is the ODBC user included in sharing?

Comment: @NicolaiKant Yes

Comment: For odbcDriverConnect try to specify the full path to the driver

Comment: @NicolaiKant that's interesting. Now the error message I get is: [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle' : file not foundODBC connection failed

Comment: Could this be Access Privileges on that file?

Comment: @NicolaiKant Not sure. I'm not sure how to check access privileges either. But, I got ahold of a Dell laptop at work today. Using the same process / code that I describe above, I was connected to my FM database in 5 minutes or less. No problems. It's really weird / ironic that I would have a much easier time connecting to FM Pro (an Apple subsidiary) on a PC, but not a Mac.

Comment: Don't think it is FileMaker problem, I used their ODBC on a Mac a few times with no problems. I think, the issue is in RODBC or R studio.

Comment: Hi @BradCannell, maybe you've already solved this problem a while ago, but could you take a look at my answer below and let me know if it solves/would have solved your issues?

Comment: Hi @Bobby, sorry for the delay. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet. I'll try to get back around to it soon.

Comment: Hi @BradCannell. Thanks very much. I know it can be tedious. I'll be presenting at a conference on this topic in a couple of days and it would be nice to have you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using odbc instead of RODBC some new R code:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      driver = "/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FileMaker ODBC",
                      server = "127.0.0.1",
                      database = "/Users/bradcannell/Dropbox/Filemaker Pro/Notes/test_r.fmp12",
                      uid = "Admin",
                      pwd = "password")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some imortant troubleshooting steps for MacOS. I've had the same error in R and therefore I think there's a good chance that this your issue. The setup of ODBC can be rather complicated since several software components with multiple versions are involved. You've already verified that ODBC sharing is on in this particular FileMaker database.

**Verify your installation of unixodbc:**

ODBC Manager is actually optional. It manages the ini files described below. But after installing unixodbc, you can also edit these ini files in a text editor without ODBC Manager.

To install Homebrew, execute this command.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, install unixodbc. This provides for ODBC connectivity at the system level.

brew update
brew install unixodbc

**Verify the driver:**

The driver should be installed here:

```
/Library/ODBC/FileMaker\ ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS
```

That folder will contain these two files:

```
SetupToolTemplate   fmodbc.so
```

Here's the full driver path:

```
/Library/ODBC/FileMaker\ ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so
```

**Verify the config files:**

The folder

```
/Library/ODBC
```

should contain these files:

```
FileMaker ODBC.bundle   odbc.ini        odbcinst.ini
```

Additionally, the unixodbc should contain only the latest version. If you have an earlier version, delete it. Now, only 2.3.4 is present.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4
```

also contains

```
odbc.ini        odbcinst.ini
```

**Mirror the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files:**

As described above, there are two copies of each of these files in two different locations. Make sure that the contents of both are equal. That means both copies of odbcinst.ini will define the drivers. And both copies of odbc.ini will contain the connections. Maybe this isn't 100% necessary, but it's what I needed to do.

**Test with isql:**

```
B:etc bobby$ isql -v DSNname admin password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

If you still have any issues after completing these steps, please share additional details so that I can update the answer.